# Replace image with another image in button after clicked

Tags: android, button

I have used a button as a menu. I have used down arrow and up arrow images inside this button. By default down arrow image is shown when I clicked the button I want that this down arrow image change into up arrow and it should remain enable.

it is my button declaration in xml file

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patientUtilityButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Patient Utilities"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/patient_utility_selector"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

and it is my drawable file for replacing image after click button

```
<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down_float" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up_float" />
```

it is replacing image but after pressing same down arrow image is showing.Please somebody help.

Comment: I use CheckBox for this in my application.. and I set drawable properties for this, and use android:button="@null" . Now Its perfactily look like button. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Button you should use toggle button.
Sample code listed below.

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/patientUtilityButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/check"   //check.xml
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

create check.xml file in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_image"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very Simple. 
you can use ImageButton or Button.

within your xml file set back ground to imageButton like follow

```
 android:background="@drawable/button_down"
```

and upon on click of that image button like

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_up);
        }
    });
```

hope this is going to help you.